# How to make sure PHP version is above a certain version in order to run code?

Tags: php, version

I'm making a script that will be used on a multitude of servers, so in my install file, I need to find what version the server is running so the file can determine whether or not to install the script.

Instead of using an array with all the versions that would be allowed and running through a loop to see if anything matches, what's an easier way to make sure they're running a new enough version of PHP?

Comment: [**`version_compare()`**](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.version-compare.php) - Something like `if(version_compare(CURRENT_PHP_VERSION, REQUIRED_PHP_VERSION) >= 0) {`

Comment: phpversion: http://us3.php.net//manual/en/function.phpversion.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a check between the current version and whatever version requirement you have.

```
define("REQUIRED_VERSION", "5.5.13");
if(!version_compare(PHP_VERSION, REQUIRED_VERSION, "<"))
{
    // Current PHP version < required version
}
```